# Overriding private methods in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, private-methods

As succinctly described [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ309_006.htm), overriding private methods in Java is invalid because a parent class's private methods are "automatically final, and hidden from the derived class".  My question is largely academic.

How is it *not* a violation of encapsulation to not allow a parent's private method to be "overridden" (ie, implemented independently, with the same signature, in a child class)?  A parent's private method cannot be accessed or inherited by a child class, in line with principles of encapsulation.  It is hidden.

So, why should the child class be restricted from implementing its own method with the same name/signature?  Is there a good theoretical foundation for this, or is this just a pragmatic solution of some sort?  Do other languages (C++ or C#) have different rules on this?

Comment: I think you may be a little confused on the meaning of "override".

Comment: Thanks mmyers .. I do not believe I am confused on the meaning of "override", although admittedly, my description has points of ambiguity largely due to confusion on the need for the @Override syntax in java to achieve an override.

Comment: The reason I said that is that you started by saying "Overriding private methods in Java is invalid" - which is either misleading or wrong, depending on what you mean by "invalid". I see you've clarified it below.

Answer (score 70):

You can't *override* a private method, but you can introduce one in a derived class without a problem. This compiles fine:

```
class Base
{
   private void foo()
   {
   }
}

class Child extends Base
{
    private void foo()
    {
    }
}
```

Note that if you try to apply the `@Override` annotation to `Child.foo()` you'll get a compile-time error. So long as you have your compiler/IDE set to give you warnings or errors if you're *missing* an `@Override` annotation, all should be well. Admittedly I prefer the C# approach of `override` being a keyword, but it was obviously too late to do that in Java.

As for C#'s handling of "overriding" a private method - a private method can't be virtual in the first place, but you can certainly introduce a new private method with the same name as a private method in the base class.

Comment: As I understand this, you'll only get an error if you insist on putting an `@override` annotation on the method in your child class.

Comment: @Carl: Yes, I was just editing to say that you'll get an error if you *do* try to claim it's overriding a method when it's not.

Comment: your answer reminds me the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953530/why-does-java-prohibit-static-fields-in-inner-classes/1953580#1953580 -- most answers just assert the facts "no you can't" and explain what you can do to workaround these facts, but they don't really try to answer the question "why it's decided like this?"

Comment: @Gregory: I don't see why. In this case I'm correcting the OP's misunderstanding - he thought you couldn't do something which in fact you can, which means there's no "why" to answer.

Comment: Exactly; this clearly isn't a workaround. The OP's assumption is incorrect, as he's conflating the concept of overriding with the keyword. You can do the former, but the latter is invalid (as far as the subclass knows, there is no method to override).

Comment: @Jon: my bad, I interpreted the question as "why can't you override private methods?"

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Your answer is very helpful and made me reconsider the cause of  my issue.  I was wrongly assuming the cause of my issue.  I think my issue has to do with the way I was setting up my constructor.  I will add detail to the main thread.

Comment: @Jon: I have added clarification in light of all comments here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000137/overriding-private-methods-in-java/2002872#2002872

Comment: It should be noted that if there's a method `Base.boo()` which calls `foo()`, then it's going to be calling `Base.foo()` instead of `Child.foo()`

Comment: Is there an issue if I change the visibility of that method to protected in parent so that I can Override it. I know in general we shouldn't change visibility because of a change we need to make but only child would have access to it in this case so not a big violation.

Comment: @Sara: That's a very broad question. If you make it protected, *any* subclass can not only override it, but call it. It becomes part of the API which is hard to change later on. Whether that's an issue for you or not is very context-specific... if it's all within a company, it may be feasible. If it's an open source project, it's a bigger decision.

Comment: @Jon Thank you, makes sense.

Comment: It should also be noted that if there's a method `Child.boo()` which calls `foo()`, then it's going to be calling `Child.foo()` as expected. Jon's code snippet is an example of method *hiding*, which applies to `private` and `static` methods. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 29):

Well, allowing private methods to be overwritten will either cause a leak of encapsulation or a security risk. If we assume that it were **possible**, then we’d get the following situation:

1. Let's say that there's a private method `boolean hasCredentials()` then an extended class could simply override it like this:

   ```
   boolean hasCredentials() { return true; }
   ```

   thus breaking the security check.
2. The only way for the original class to prevent this would be to declare its method `final`. But now, this is leaks implementation information through the encapsulation, because a derived class now *cannot* create a method `hasCredentials` any more – it would clash with the one defined in the base class.

   That’s bad: lets say this method doesn’t exist at first in `Base`. Now, an implementor can legitimately derive a class `Derived` and give it a method `hasCredentials` which works as expected.

   But now, a *new* version of the original `Base` class is released. Its public interface doesn’t change (and neither do its invariants) so we must expect that it doesn’t break existing code. Only it does, because now there’s a name clash with a method in a derived class.

I think the question stems from a misunderstanding:

> How is it /not/ a violation of encapsulation to not allow a parent's private method to be "overridden" (ie, implemented independently, with the same signature, in a child class)

The text inside the parentheses is the *opposite* of the text before it. Java *does* allow you to “independently implement [a private method], with the same signature, in a child class”. Not allowing this would violate encapsulation, as I’ve explained above.

But “to not allow a parent's private method to be "overridden"” is something different, and necessary to *ensure* encapsulation.

Comment: @rsp: no. Jon’s and my answers are not in disagreement, on the contrary.

Comment: Ok, I misread your points 1. and 2. At first glance it wasn't clear to me you were describing a hypothetical situation.

Comment: @Konrad:  That helps a lot to shed some light on the "why".  However, for item 1., could this not be addressed by looking at the type of the object calling the method (or calling a public method which in turn calls the private method)?

Comment: @Konrad: As I detail in my own answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000137/overriding-private-methods-in-java/2002872#2002872), I created a scenario where I was calling an instance of a derived class which contained its own new private method (not overridden), but, which inherited a public method that called the private method.  I called the public method on an instance of the derived class, but it executed the parent's private method.  I was surprised by this result.

Answer (score 17):

> "Do other languages (C++ or C#) have different rules on this?"

Well, C++ has different rules: the static or dynamic member function binding process and the access privileges enforcements are orthogonal.

Giving a member function the `private` access privilege modiﬁer means that this function can only be called by its declaring class, not by others (not even the derived classes). When you declare a `private` member function as `virtual`, even pure virtual (`virtual void foo() = 0;`), you allow the base class to beneﬁt from specialization while still enforcing the access privileges.

When it comes to `virtual` member functions, access privileges tells you what you are supposed to do:

- `private virtual` means that you are allowed to specialize the behavior but the invocation of the member function is made by the base class, surely in a controlled fashion
- `protected virtual` means that you should / must invoke the upper class version of the member function when overriding it

So, in C++, access privilege and virtualness are independent of each other. Determining whether the function is to be statically or dynamically bound is the last step in resolving a function call.

Finally, the Template Method design pattern should be preferred over `public virtual` member functions.

Reference: [Conversations: Virtually Yours](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403760)

The article gives a practical use of a `private virtual` member function.

---

ISO/IEC 14882-2003 §3.4.1

> Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name; the declarations are said to form a set of overloaded functions (13.1). Overload resolution (13.3) takes place after name lookup has succeeded. The access rules (clause 11) are considered only once name lookup and function overload resolution (if applicable) have succeeded. Only after name lookup, function overload resolution (if applicable) and access checking have succeeded are the attributes introduced by the name’s declaration used further in expression processing (clause 5).

ISO/IEC 14882-2003 §5.2.2

> The function called in a member function call is normally selected according to the static type of the object expression (clause 10), but if that function isvirtualand is not specified using aqualified-idthen the function actually called will be the final overrider (10.3) of the selected function in the dynamic type of the object expression [Note: the dynamic type is the type of the object pointed or referred to by the current value of the object expression.

Answer (score 7):

> A parent's private method cannot be accessed or inherited by a child class, inline with principles of encapsulation. It is hidden.
>
> So, why should the child class be
> restricted from implementing its own
> method with the same name/signature?

There is no such restriction. You can do that without any problems, it's just not called "overriding".

Overridden methods are subject to dynamic dispatch, i.e. the method that is actually called is selected at runtime depending on the actual type of the object it's called on. With private method, that does not happen (and should not, as per your first statement). And that's what is meant by the statement "private methods can't be overridden".

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misinterpreting what that post says. It's *not* saying that the child class is "restricted from implementing its own method with the same name/signature."

Here's the code, slightly edited:

```
public class PrivateOverride {
  private static Test monitor = new Test();

  private void f() {
    System.out.println("private f()");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrivateOverride po = new Derived();
    po.f();
    });
  }
}

class Derived extends PrivateOverride {
  public void f() {
    System.out.println("public f()");
  }
}
```

And the quote:

> You might reasonably expect the output to be “public f( )”,

The reason for that quote is that the variable `po` actually holds an instance of Derived. However, since the method is defined as private, the compiler actually looks at the type of the variable, rather than the type of the object. And it translates the method call into *invokespecial* (I think that's the right opcode, haven't checked JVM spec) rather than *invokeinstance*.

Comment: @kdgregory: I think this gets close to what I experienced, but as I describe in my answer to my own post(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000137/overriding-private-methods-in-java/2002872#2002872), I instantiated an instance of the child class and accessed an inherited public method which called the private method in question, but the result given was the parent's private method result, not the child's.  I think the way I setup the constructor in the child may have created the same scenario you describe here, even though my object creation code is different syntax than what yours shows.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a matter of choice and definition. The reason you can't do this in java is because the specification says so, but the question were more why the specification says so.

The fact that C++ allows this (even if we use virtual keyword to force dynamic dispatch) shows that there is no inherent reason why you couldn't allow this.

However it seem to be perfectly legal to **replace** the method:

```
class B {
    private int foo() 
    {
        return 42;
    }

    public int bar()
    {
        return foo();
    }
}

class D extends B {
    private int foo()
    {
        return 43;
    }

    public int frob()
    {
        return foo();
    }
}
```

Seems to compile OK (on my compiler), but the D.foo is not related to B.foo (ie it doesn't override it) - bar() always return 42 (by calling B.foo) and frob() always returns 43 (by calling D.foo) no matter whether called on a B or D instance.

One reason that Java does not allow override the method would be that they didn't like to allow the method to be changed as in Konrad Rudolph's example. Note that C++ differs here as you need to use the "virtual" keyword in order to get dynamic dispatch - by default it hasn't so you can't modify code in base class that relies on the hasCredentials method. The above example also protects against this as the D.foo does not replace calls to foo from B.

Answer (score 0):

When the method is private, it's not visible to its child. So there is no meaning of overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for using the term override incorrectly and inconsistent with my description.  My description describes the scenario.  The following code extends Jon Skeet's example to portray my scenario:

```
class Base {
   public void callFoo() {
     foo();
   }
   private void foo() {
   }
}

class Child extends Base {
    private void foo() {
    }
}
```

Usage is like the following:

```
Child c = new Child();
c.callFoo();
```

The issue I experienced is that the parent foo() method was being called even though, as the code shows, I was calling callFoo() on the child instance variable.  I thought I was defining a new private method foo() in Child() which the inherited callFoo() method would call, but I think some of what kdgregory has said may apply to my scenario - possibly due to the way the derived class constructor is calling super(), or perhaps not.

There was no compiler warning in Eclipse and the code did compile.  The result was unexpected.

Comment: as I said in my answer, in C++ `callFoo()` would call `Child::foo()`

Comment: Yeah, you have to use `protected` for that sort of thing in Java. And the compiler couldn't warn you because it has no way of knowing what you intended; your code is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond anything said before, there's a very semantic reason for not allowing private methods to be overridden...THEY'RE PRIVATE!!!

If I write a class, and I indicate that a method is 'private', it should be completely unseeable by the outside world.  Nobody should be able access it, override it, or anything else.  I simply ought to be able to know that it is MY method exclusively and that nobody else is going to muck with it or depend on it.  It could not be considered private if someone could muck with it.  I believe that it's that simple really.

Answer (score -1):

A class is defined by what methods it makes available and how they behave. Not how those are implemented internally (e.g. via calls to private methods).

Because encapsulation has to do with behavior and not implementation details, private methods have nothing to do with the idea encapsulation. In a sense, your question makes no sense. It's like asking "How is putting cream in coffee not a violation of encapsulation?"

Presumably the private method is used by something that is public. You can override that. In doing so, you've changed behavior.