# How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText

Tags: android-widget, android-edittext, android, android-keypad

In my application, there is a registration screen, where i do not want the user to be able to copy/paste text into the `EditText` field. I have set an `onLongClickListener` on each `EditText` so that the context menu showing copy/paste/inputmethod  and other options does not show up. So the user won't be able to copy/ paste into the Edit fields.

```
 OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // prevent context menu from being popped up, so that user
            // cannot copy/paste from/into any EditText fields.
            return true;
        }
    };
```

But the problem arises if the user has enabled a third-party keyboard other than the Android default, which may have a button to copy/paste or which may show the same context menu. So how do i disable copy/paste in that scenario ?

Please let me know if there are other ways to copy/paste as well. (and possibly how to disable them)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the "paste" operation comes from an IME, then you have no standard way of distinguishing it from normal keystrokes. One idea to try is to measure the time between each character's arrival and if the time is too short, then the characters are coming from a "paste" operation.

Comment: seems to be dirty soloution! worth a look though.

Comment: use android:longClickable="false"

Comment: The conclusion for everyone seems to be that: you really can't do it nicely. However, for my personal purposes, I want to disable paste because I can't handle certain characters being present, and paste can allow them into my EditText. A solution then is to add a text changed listener, and in the afterTextChanged method, remove those characters if they're there. You can add multiple listeners, and thus create one that prevents the text from being too long, invalid characters, etc. This is *not* preferable. But if anyone was looking for a half decent workaround, I think this is it.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

If you are using API level 11 or above then you can stop copy,paste,cut and custom context menus from appearing by.

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**Returning false from onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu) will prevent the action mode from being started(Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste actions).**

Comment: what about api level below 13?

Comment: Dont understand either comments, this sample works api11+, pre-api11 there wasn't copy and paste IIRC

Comment: Not working for me.Paste button will appear in case of tapping on blue cursor indicator.

Comment: Also not working for me. On Double tapping the menu of copy-paste is showing.

Comment: this doesn't working anymore on android 6.0 ,check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even

Comment: This solution is good(but not perfect), unfortunately, in my case it caused NPE in android part of the code (sometimes, during "monkey testing"), so I had to find another solution, see my answer below

Comment: It's work only when EditText is not empty, It's Doest not work when edittext have some texts.

Comment: @Humble coder the above solution is not working moto g5 mobile and in OS oreo.

the solution for all devices is use below method :

edittext.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback();

Answer (score 144):

Best method is to use:

```
etUsername.setLongClickable(false);
```

Comment: Or, just in xml `android:longClickable="false"` :)

Comment: Paste button will appear in case of tapping on blue cursor indicator.

Comment: This will certainly prevent the view from being long clickable, but the editing controls can also be requested by double tapping on text, which means that this solution is not complete. Keep this in mind for your purposes.

Comment: Also, keyboard shortcuts could still work (Ctrl+C) w/external keyboards.

Comment: This does not work on Ice Cream Sandwich because the clipboard options can be opened by double tapping text, as well as long tapping.

Comment: but I still want to select text, just without widget

Answer (score 56):

You can do this by disabling the long press of the EditText

To implement it, just add the following line in the xml -

```
android:longClickable="false"
```

Comment: problem was that my app user has a third party keyboard which has a copy and paste button.

Comment: another problem is you can select the text by double tap and it shows copy/paste again

Answer (score 41):

I am able to disable copy-and-paste functionality with the following:

```
textField.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
    }
});

textField.setLongClickable(false);
textField.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Hope it works for you ;-)

Comment: This is the exact same solution I ended up with based on the other answers above. This should be marked as the correct solution since it handles the edge cases the others do not

Comment: This option blocks the copy but you can still paste by clicking on the cursor.

Answer (score 16):

Kotlin solution:

```
fun TextView.disableCopyPaste() {
    isLongClickable = false
    setTextIsSelectable(false)
    customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {}
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call this method on your `TextView`:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    priceEditText.disableCopyPaste()
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm using this approach, but I'm getting `Type mismatch` error with this description `Required:ActionMode.Callback! Found: `on this part `object: ActionMode.Callback`. Any idea why it might not be working?

Comment: Try `object : android.view.ActionMode.Callback` instead

Answer (score 12):

here is a best way to disable cut copy paste of editText work in all version

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        editText.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                menu.clear();
            }
        });
    } else {
        editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode,
                    MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, I just had to add 
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331404/3063884), and [disabled long-click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821250/3063884) solutions, it's necessary to [prevent the PASTE/REPLACE menus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27869983/3063884) from appearing when the text selection handle is clicked, as per the image below:

[image: Text selection handle with paste menu]

The solution lies in preventing PASTE/REPLACE menu from appearing in the [`show()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/Editor.java#Editor.ActionPopupWindow.show%28%29) method of the (non-documented) `android.widget.Editor` class. Before the menu appears, a check is done to `if (!canPaste && !canSuggest) return;`. The two methods that are used as the basis to set these variables are both in the `EditText` class:

- [`isSuggestionsEnabled()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.isSuggestionsEnabled%28%29) is [public](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#isSuggestionsEnabled()), and may thus be overridden.
- [`canPaste()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.canPaste%28%29) is not, and thus must be hidden by [introducing a function of the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000156/3063884) in the derived class.

A more complete answer is [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28893714/3063884).

Comment: This is the CORRECT and COMPLETE solution

Comment: In some devices instead of Paste Clipboard option is visible, acts as paste only. i checked links but i am able to prevent paste but not clipboard. any idea ?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't wan't to disable long click because you need to perform some functionality on long click than returning true is a better option to do so.

Your edittext long click will be like this.

```
edittext.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //  Do Something or Don't
            return true;
      }
});
```

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)
Returning "True" will indicate that long click have been handled so no need to perform default operations.

I tested this on API level 16, 22 and 25. Its working fine for me. Hope this will help.

Comment: Good one. Alternatively, just set `android:longClickable="false"` in XML

Answer (score 4):

Here is a hack to disable "paste" popup. You have to override `EditText` method:

```
@Override
public int getSelectionStart() {
    for (StackTraceElement element : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
        if (element.getMethodName().equals("canPaste")) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return super.getSelectionStart();
}
```

Similar can be done for the other actions.

Comment: can you tell for Clipboard disable

Answer (score 4):

I've tested this solution and this works

```
    mSubdomainEditText.setLongClickable(false);
    mSubdomainEditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

      public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
      }

      public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
      }

      public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
      }

      public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: i used this code it prevent from clipboard,copy option.Thank you

Answer (score 4):

i added **Extension Function** in **Kotlin** language :

```
fun EditText.disableTextSelection() {
    this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(object : android.view.ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: android.view.ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: android.view.ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: android.view.ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: android.view.ActionMode?) {
        }
    })
}
```

you can use it like this :

```
edit_text.disableTextSelection()
```

also added below line in your xml :

```
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI provides an `EditText` with a method

`myEditText.disableCopyAndPaste()`.

And it's works on the old API

Comment: This does exactly the same as the half-solution provided by http://stackoverflow.com/a/22756538/3063884. See the code: https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI/blob/master/Library/src/com/neopixl/pixlui/components/edittext/EditText.java#L304 ... This approach still doesn't prevent the text selection handler from showing "PASTE" if there's text in the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable `ActionMode` for copy/pasting, you need to override 2 callbacks. This works for both `TextView` and `EditText` (or `TextInputEditText`)

```
import android.view.ActionMode

fun TextView.disableCopyPaste() {
  isLongClickable = false
  setTextIsSelectable(false)
  customSelectionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu) = false
    override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu) = false
    override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem) = false
    override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {}
  }
  //disable action mode when edittext gain focus at first
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    customInsertionActionModeCallback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
      override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu) = false
      override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu) = false
      override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem) = false
      override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {}
    }
  }
}
```

This extension is based off above @Alexandr solution and worked fine for me.

Comment: this solution is more comprehensive

Answer (score 3):

its very late but may it help someone .

add these lines in your edittext xml

```
android:longClickable="false"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

Comment: Thanks, its working for me to apply for TextInputEditText. Well answer

Answer (score 2):

@Zain Ali, your answer works on API 11. I just wanted to suggest a way to do in on API 10 as well. Since I had to maintain my project API on that version, I was constantly playing with the functions available in 2.3.3 and got a possibility to do it. I have share the snippet below. I tested the code and it was working for me. I did this snippet on an urgency. Feel free to improve the code if there are any changes that can be done..

```
// A custom TouchListener is being implemented which will clear out the focus 
// and gain the focus for the EditText, in few milliseconds so the selection 
// will be cleared and hence the copy paste option wil not pop up.
// the respective EditText should be set with this listener 
// tmpEditText.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(tmpEditText, tmpImm));

public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    long click = 0;
    EditText mEtView;
    InputMethodManager imm;

    public MyTouchListener(EditText etView, InputMethodManager im) {
        mEtView = etView;
        imm = im;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (click !=0 && ( curr - click) < 30) {

                mEtView.setSelected(false);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mEtView.setSelected(true);
                        mEtView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        imm.showSoftInput(mEtView, InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN);
                    }
                },25);

            return true;
            }
            else {
                if (click == 0)
                    click = curr;
                else
                    click = 0;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mEtView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        mEtView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        imm.showSoftInput(mEtView, InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN);
                    }
                },25);
            return true;
            }

        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            mEtView.setSelected(false);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mEtView.setSelected(true);
                    mEtView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                    mEtView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                    imm.showSoftInput(mEtView, InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN);
                }
            },25);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For smartphone with clipboard, is possible prevent like this.

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (source.length() > 1) {
                return "";
            }  return null;
        }
    }});
```

Comment: This fails because auto-correct, at least on my device, sometimes wants to replace characters at the same time it adds the newly typed characters. When this happens, this code thinks it's a paste and the whole auto-correcting (underlined) word is erased. The fix is to see if the source length is the destination length plus one - in that case, it's ok to accept the characters. But this is a kludge and also has the effect of disabling the "tap a word" to do auto-complete since that is exactly like a paste operation.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Clipboard, check against the input and the time the input is "typed". If the Clipboard has the same text and it is too fast, delete the pasted input.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is very simple

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_0 = findViewById(R.id.et_0);

    et_0.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //to keep the text selection capability available ( selection cursor)
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //to prevent the menu from appearing
            menu.clear();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
   }
}
```

[--------> preview <---------](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPmiV.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Try Following custome class for prevant copy and paste in `Edittext`

```
public class SegoeUiEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
private final Context context;


@Override
public boolean isSuggestionsEnabled() {
    return false;
}
public SegoeUiEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public SegoeUiEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

public SegoeUiEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}


private void setFonts(Context context) {
    this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Fonts/Helvetica-Normal.ttf"));
}

private void init() {

        setTextIsSelectable(false);
        this.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionModeCallbackInterceptor());
        this.setLongClickable(false);

}
@Override
public int getSelectionStart() {

    for (StackTraceElement element : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
        if (element.getMethodName().equals("canPaste")) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return super.getSelectionStart();
}
/**
 * Prevents the action bar (top horizontal bar with cut, copy, paste, etc.) from appearing
 * by intercepting the callback that would cause it to be created, and returning false.
 */
private class ActionModeCallbackInterceptor implements ActionMode.Callback, android.view.ActionMode.Callback {
    private final String TAG = SegoeUiEditText.class.getSimpleName();

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) { return false; }
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) { return false; }
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) { return false; }
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above do not take into account pasting with hardware keyboards (Ctrl+v). The easiest solution is to set a TextWatcher on your EditText, and filter characters you want or don't want in the afterTextChanged method. This works for all situations, i.e. typed characters, pastes, auto suggestions and auto corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in my case i had to set the callback for both **selection** and **insertion** and only then i got the copy/paste pop-up to not appear anymore.
Something like this :

```
 private void disableCopyPaste() {
    input.setLongClickable(false);
    input.setTextIsSelectable(false);
    final ActionMode.Callback disableCopyPasteCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        }
    };
    input.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(disableCopyPasteCallback);
    input.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(disableCopyPasteCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than completely disabling all actions on the EditText, you may want to prevent only certain actions (like cut/copy, but not paste):

```
/**
 * Prevent copy/cut of the (presumably sensitive) contents of this TextView.
 */
fun TextView.disableCopyCut() {
    setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(
        object : Callback {
            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?) = false

            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
                menu?.apply {
                    removeItem(android.R.id.copy)
                    removeItem(android.R.id.cut)
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?) = false

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
                // no-op
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Actions that can be selectively removed:

```
removeItem(android.R.id.copy)
removeItem(android.R.id.cut)
removeItem(android.R.id.paste)
removeItem(android.R.id.shareText) // Share
removeItem(android.R.id.textAssist) // Open with Chrome
```

Comment: Kotlin correction: if we are not returning anything, then why use 'apply' extension function instead of 'run'? 'run' is more correct here.

Comment: Both run and apply have return values. A return value is not needed/used in this case, so either extension is equally suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when you create an input filter to avoid entry of unwanted characters, pasting such characters into the edit text is having no effect. So this sort of solves my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me was to create custom Edittext and override following method:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

private int mPreviousCursorPosition;

@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    CharSequence text = getText();
    if (text != null) {
        if (selStart != selEnd) {
            setSelection(mPreviousCursorPosition, mPreviousCursorPosition);
            return;
        }
    }
    mPreviousCursorPosition = selStart;
    super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use.

```
myEditext.setCursorVisible(false);

       myEditext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode,
                MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Who is looking for a solution in Kotlin use the below class as a custom widget and use it in the xml.

class SecureEditText : TextInputEditText {

```
/** This is a replacement method for the base TextView class' method of the same name. This method
 * is used in hidden class android.widget.Editor to determine whether the PASTE/REPLACE popup
 * appears when triggered from the text insertion handle. Returning false forces this window
 * to never appear.
 * @return false
 */
override fun isSuggestionsEnabled(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun getSelectionStart(): Int {
    for (element in Thread.currentThread().stackTrace) {
        if (element.methodName == "canPaste") {
            return -1
        }
    }
    return super.getSelectionStart()
}

public override fun onSelectionChanged(start: Int, end: Int) {

    val text = text
    if (text != null) {
        if (start != text.length || end != text.length) {
            setSelection(text.length, text.length)
            return
        }
    }

    super.onSelectionChanged(start, end)
}

companion object {
    private val EDITTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_COPY_AND_PASTE = "isCopyPasteDisabled"
    private val PACKAGE_NAME = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    disableCopyAndPaste(context, attrs)
}

/**
 * Disable Copy and Paste functionality on EditText
 *
 * @param context Context object
 * @param attrs   AttributeSet Object
 */
private fun disableCopyAndPaste(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {
    val isDisableCopyAndPaste = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(
        PACKAGE_NAME,
        EDITTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_COPY_AND_PASTE, true
    )
    if (isDisableCopyAndPaste && !isInEditMode()) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        this.setLongClickable(false)
        this.setOnTouchListener(BlockContextMenuTouchListener(inputMethodManager))
    }
}

/**
 * Perform Focus Enabling Task to the widget with the help of handler object
 * with some delay
 * @param inputMethodManager is used to show the key board
 */
private fun performHandlerAction(inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager) {
    val postDelayedIntervalTime: Long = 25
    Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
        this@SecureEditText.setSelected(true)
        this@SecureEditText.requestFocusFromTouch()
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(
            this@SecureEditText,
            InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN
        )
    }, postDelayedIntervalTime)
}

/**
 * Class to Block Context Menu on double Tap
 * A custom TouchListener is being implemented which will clear out the focus
 * and gain the focus for the EditText, in few milliseconds so the selection
 * will be cleared and hence the copy paste option wil not pop up.
 * the respective EditText should be set with this listener
 *
 * @param inputMethodManager is used to show the key board
 */
private inner class BlockContextMenuTouchListener internal constructor(private val inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager) :
    View.OnTouchListener {
    private var lastTapTime: Long = 0
    val TIME_INTERVAL_BETWEEN_DOUBLE_TAP = 30
    override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.getAction() === MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val currentTapTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            if (lastTapTime != 0L && currentTapTime - lastTapTime < TIME_INTERVAL_BETWEEN_DOUBLE_TAP) {
                this@SecureEditText.setSelected(false)
                performHandlerAction(inputMethodManager)
                return true
            } else {
                if (lastTapTime == 0L) {
                    lastTapTime = currentTapTime
                } else {
                    lastTapTime = 0
                }
                performHandlerAction(inputMethodManager)
                return true
            }
        } else if (event.getAction() === MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            this@SecureEditText.setSelected(false)
            performHandlerAction(inputMethodManager)
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A widely compatible solution (from Android 1.5 onwards) is

```
@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
    switch (id){
        case android.R.id.cut:
            onTextCut();
            return false;
        case android.R.id.paste:
            onTextPaste();
            return false;
        case android.R.id.copy:
            onTextCopy();
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time, removing the paste option in **ContextMenu** of EditText I have followed the below code in Java.

**NoMenuEditText.Java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText;

/**
 * custom edit text
 */


public class NoMenuEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    private static final String EDITTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_COPY_AND_PASTE = "isCopyPasteDisabled";
    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto";

    public NoMenuEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoMenuEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        EnableDisableCopyAndPaste(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Enable/Disable Copy and Paste functionality on EditText
     *
     * @param context Context object
     * @param attrs   AttributeSet Object
     */
    private void EnableDisableCopyAndPaste(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        boolean isDisableCopyAndPaste = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(PACKAGE_NAME,
                EDITTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_COPY_AND_PASTE, false);
        if (isDisableCopyAndPaste && !isInEditMode()) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            this.setLongClickable(false);
            this.setOnTouchListener(new BlockContextMenuTouchListener
                    (inputMethodManager));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Perform Focus Enabling Task to the widget with the help of handler object
     * with some delay
     */
    private void performHandlerAction(final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager) {
        int postDelayedIntervalTime = 25;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NoMenuEditText.this.setSelected(true);
                NoMenuEditText.this.requestFocusFromTouch();
                inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(NoMenuEditText.this,
                        InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN);
            }
        }, postDelayedIntervalTime);
    }

    /**
     * Class to Block Context Menu on double Tap
     * A custom TouchListener is being implemented which will clear out the focus
     * and gain the focus for the EditText, in few milliseconds so the selection
     * will be cleared and hence the copy paste option wil not pop up.
     * the respective EditText should be set with this listener
     */
    private class BlockContextMenuTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        private static final int TIME_INTERVAL_BETWEEN_DOUBLE_TAP = 30;
        private InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;
        private long lastTapTime = 0;

        BlockContextMenuTouchListener(InputMethodManager inputMethodManager) {
            this.inputMethodManager = inputMethodManager;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                long currentTapTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (lastTapTime != 0 && (currentTapTime - lastTapTime)
                        < TIME_INTERVAL_BETWEEN_DOUBLE_TAP) {
                    NoMenuEditText.this.setSelected(false);
                    performHandlerAction(inputMethodManager);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    if (lastTapTime == 0) {
                        lastTapTime = currentTapTime;
                    } else {
                        lastTapTime = 0;
                    }
                    performHandlerAction(inputMethodManager);
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                NoMenuEditText.this.setSelected(false);
                performHandlerAction(inputMethodManager);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        CharSequence text = getText();
        if (text != null) {
            if (selStart != text.length() || selEnd != text.length()) {
                setSelection(text.length(), text.length());
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isSuggestionsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectionStart() {
        for (StackTraceElement element : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            if (element.getMethodName().equals("canPaste")) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return super.getSelectionStart();
    }



}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NoMenuEditText edt_username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edt_username = (NoMenuEditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);

   
        edt_username.setLongClickable(false);
        edt_username.setTextIsSelectable(false);

        edt_username.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                return false;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

            }
        });
        
    }

}
```

**drawable- zeropx.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <size
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="NoMenuEditText">
        <attr name="isCopyPasteDisabled" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

At Last, I finally Removed the **paste option** from the **Context Menu** of **EditText**

Thank you **StackOverflow posts** and http://androidinformative.com/disabling-context-menu/

Answer (score 0):

```
 editText.apply {
        setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
               if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                      requestFocus()
                      setSelection(text.toString().length)
                      showKeyboard()
                      return@setOnTouchListener true
               }
        }
 }

fun View.showKeyboard() {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(this, 0)
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar to GnrlKnowledge, you can clear the Clipboard

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html

If you want, preserve the text in the Clipboard, and on onDestroy, you can set it again.

Answer (score -1):

You may try android:focusableInTouchMode="false".

Comment: It will never Work