# How to enable/disable clipboard for an EditText

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to enable/disable clipboard in an edittext.
How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no means to "enable/disable clipboard in an edittext", sorry.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html