# How to implement edit text which doesn't show copy/paste menu

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm having trouble with making custom EditText component. I want copy/paste/select all feature to be fully prevented.

Long click case is easy to prevent.

But there are 2 cases I've also seen which opens the menu and I'm having troubles with.

1. Double tap EditText (can be blocked for example to eat douple tap event)
   But this removes the selection mode feature.
2. Some devices launch the menu when just clicking insert controller.

So I want to have insertion and selection controllers visible and usable, but the HandleView menu to be never shown.

Do I have to copy paste and override TextView class or is there simplier hack solution for this.

Br,
Niko

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext

Comment: Disabling long click solves only that problem. Theres still menu with insertion and selection handles and that post doesnt resolve the issue. It only prevents paste but still the menu is available to user.