# Android EditText without QuickAction

Tags: android, android-edittext

My problem is, when I select some text in an EditText (version 4.0.3), a QuickAction (showing several options like cut, copy, paste) will appear near the selected text. I Don't need this popup, so how can I turn it off or something like that? Thanks

Comment: follow the link below

[edut text without cut copy paste][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext

Answer (score 1):

```
    edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {      
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {                 return false;             }            
  public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                               }           
   public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {                 return false;             }              public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {                 return false;             }         });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add callback for your editText like this :

```
YOUR_EDITTEXT_OBJECT.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```