# Securing Data being 'Cut and Pasted'

Tags: android

Anyone know if you can block the cut\paste functionality on Android?  Or even better, can you restrict the data cut to only be pasted into other places in your own App?

I want to restrict private data from being 'cut' out of my app, and 'pasted' into somewhere un-trusted.

Comment: To block cut/paste you can try to cancel the long press event for the textview or any control that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion and suggestions in this so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext). But generally these involve intercepting the long press/context menu event on the edit texts within your app.