# Disable cut and copy (but not paste) in an Android application?

Tags: android, centralized

I have a specific request. I need to disable cut and copy operations in my application, but not the ability to paste.

All the questions asked on here focus on disabling the overflow menus from being called when double tapping or long tapping on EditTexts, but, as I have around 400 EditTexts in my project, I wondered if there is something that can be done on application-level from one place (or fewer than 400 places).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756538/4000556) answer covers how to disable all the menus on an EditText. I have not tried it, so I can't confirm if it works, but maybe that solution can be modified, so that it brings the functionality that I want?

**However**, I would still like to know if there is a more centralized way to do this effectively.

If there is any more info that I can provide - please feel free to inquire it from me.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.