# Disable copy paste in a android

Tags: android, copy, paste

I want to disable copy paste in all of my android page and no one cant long touch on my application .

`android:longClickable="false"` it dosent work.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175041/android-how-to-totally-disable-copy-and-paste-function-in-edittext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to TOTALLY disable copy and paste function in Edittext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175041/android-how-to-totally-disable-copy-and-paste-function-in-edittext)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

In xml, disable the long-click in the EditText:
`android:longClickable="false".`

Also, you have to return false from these methods:

```
mEditEext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work fine. User can not able to copy your page to another app.

```
//Inside onResume and onDestroy
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)     context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboardManager.setText("");
```

Here, It will restrict for background process "Secondary app". But you can copy and paste it only inside your app.