# How to disable paste pop-up option on android

Tags: android

I have textview, from where user should be able only to copy text. So I have costumized android contextual bar and removed cut and paste options from there but during long click (when CAB is shown) little pop-up appears with paste option...
How can I remove this pop-up? Keep in mind, I need this edit text to be isselectable=true; cause user should be ablw to copy from there
[image]

I cann't copy code (privacy issues) so I print screened it
[image]

This question is different from [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext). 
Because provided correct answer, suggests to implement callback class which returns false on everything, but my callback class is different. It has overriden functionality. Also provided answer saysReturning false from onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu) will prevent the action mode from being started(Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste actions). 
This answer is different from my question, because i need user to be able to copy from textviw

Comment: No, in this post suggested correct answe is custom callback class where everything returns false, as u see, i have different callback class, and i need it for CAB

Comment: @PankajKumar please remove duplicate mark, I've editied posr

Comment: Done that. Hope you will get your answer.

Comment: by the way, code screen printed is as good (or bad) as code copied/pasted.