# Disable Long Click on SearchView EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-toolbar, android-search

I have a `SearchView` on my `Toolbar`. I works perfectly and I have no problem with it.

But the problem arises whenever I write some search term on the EditText of the SearchView and long-click on the text, the toolbar transforms into a contextual menu with paste, copy, etc options.

[image]

This also happened in other EditTexts of my app, but I solved it using

```
android:longClickable="false"
```

This entirely disables long-click event on the EditTexts and the context menu never appears. This is the behavior I want.

But how can I do the same for the SearchView? I tried to disable long-click on the SearchView but that doesn't work.

How can I reference the EditText of the SearchView and then disable the long-click event? Or is there any other better approach?

Comment: can you post your code of how you're using `SearchView` in `ToolBar` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getActivity().getString(R.string.search_files_hint));

        search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(search,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                        return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {

                        // Disabling long-click on the SearchView to remove the CAB glitch
                        TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
                        if(searchText != null){
                            searchText.setLongClickable(false);
                        }

                        return true; // Return true to expand action view
                    }
                });

    }
```

**The SearchView is not a simple View, rather a compound View consisting of a lot of Views.**

On investigating further, I found that it has a `SearchAutoComplete` view which indirectly inherits from the EditText.

So, I just found a reference for it and if its not NULL then I `setLongClickable` to `false`.

But **the trick here is to use it only when the SearchView is expanded**, otherwise the `SearchAutoComplete` view is never inflated and is always null.