# Secure text of Android APP so that no one can copy it

Tags: android, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I am developing android application. It contains lots of pages and text on those pages. I do not want user to copy these text using any mechanism like obtain text from APK. User can  make snapshots and extract text, but I will make sure that it won't be feasible for the user. If I hardcode text, then any one can extract it from APK. Is there any way to prevent users from obtaining text. What if I use SqlCipher to store text in Sqlite and then display text on Android APP? I want to store data on mobile do not want network Connectivity.

Comment: Try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/22756538/4018207

Comment: SQLcipher is your best bet. You will have to ship the database with the apk using [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)