# How to remove special keys from keyboard

Tags: android

I would like to remove the "settings" and the "paste" keys in the keyboard (EditText). How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

**EDIT:**

About possible duplicate with this thread: [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext), my question is a bit different. I am not trying to find a way to cancel the paste function in any keyboard the user may choose. In my context, the app is in kiosk mode, so user has not the privileges to change anything. And that exactly why I do not want him being able to change any keyboard config using that "setting" key in the android default keyboard...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext)

Comment: My concern is more about removing keys on the default keyboard, not for all of them. I updated my question in that way

Comment: Install some IME that does not have those keys. Write one yourself if need be. You have no means, through the SDK, of preventing an IME from having those keys.