# I am unable to make text selectable in edittext. When user tap the text for long it gets selected, I don't want text to get selected or highlighted

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
android:longClickable="false"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

I have applied these constraints on my editText, Everything is working fine, only problem is when user tap for long text gets selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

As DArkO has answered on a similar question:

"you can return true in your onLongClick listener onLongClick method? that means that you have consumed the event and it wont be passed further along."

The onLongClick listener should be added in your Java Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can set cursor to blink at the end of the text by reading the content length of your text and then display the cursor over there..
Code for that would be..

```
editProfileUserName.setSelection(editProfileUserName.getText().length()); //This line will take the selection at last index of text.

editProfileUserName.setCursorVisible(true);
```