# Android - how to disable / change editTexts 'Pin'

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I edit or disable the 'pin' for editTexts that appears when marking text? I was able to edit the underline & the cursor, but not that 'pin' because I didn't know how to call it. 
Image of the pin (pink) added.
[image: pink pin of editText]

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331404/4388512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 'pin' is called "text select handle" 
To change it you need to use these attributes:
`text_select_handle_left` and `text_select_handle_right`

Answer (score 2):

I think the colourAccent influences the colour of that pin, try changing the colour of colourAccent in color.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add these drawables with customized design/color to your drawable folder and add to style

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/MyCustomTheme">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
</style>
```