# How to hide ActionPopupWindow of Text Selection Handler of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

Actually I want to hide ActionPopupWindow (popup having SELECT ALL, CLIPBOARD options) when user click on **+** icon(refer to the attached image).

ActionPopupWindow appears when user click on the Text Selection Handler(bubble) (which appears when user tap on the text in the EditText).

I have tried to use setTextIsSelectable() method of EditText but it is not working consistently.

Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **UPDATE:** To hide the Popup already opened and showing on the screen, you need to **clear focus** of the current `EditText` or focus on other view when you clicked the plus button. See the
>   example below:

```
iconPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        yourEditText.clearFocus();
    }
});
```

---

If you want the popup never shows up at the first place, there are many ways to do it.

The simplest way is **disabling** long click and selection feature:

```
yourEditText.setLongClickable(false);
yourEditText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Second one is **overriding** action callback actions on your edittext:

```
    yourEditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You can use them separately or together according to your case.

Also you can check other options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext)

Comment: Hi Oğuzhan Döngül, thanks for the quick reply. But I need to hide ActionPopupWindow (popup having SELECT ALL, CLIPBOARD options) when user click on any button (like + icon in the attached image).

Comment: @abhishekkumargupta updated my answer and solved your actual issue.

Comment: Thanks Oğuzhan Döngül. I amazed how I skipped this simple concept of clearing focus.