# Long clickable is not working in android

Tags: android

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_Division"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
                    <com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.Common.UI.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/actventryDivName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:hint="@string/station"
                        android:maxLength="250"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/AutocompleteTheme"
                        android:longClickable="false"
                        android:theme="@style/AutocompleteTheme"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: Options are displaying]
Eventhough I made the longclickable false to the textinputLayout, It will display the cut, copy, share options. Why?

I dont need these options. What can I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331404/5370550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using API level 11 or above then you can stop copy,paste,cut and custom context menus from appearing by.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        editText.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                menu.clear();
            }
        });
    } else {
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
            }

            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Returning false from onCreateActionMode(ActionMode, Menu) will prevent the action mode from being started(Select All, Cut, Copy and Paste actions).

Comment: It is not Working for me

Comment: all options are disabled but paste option is coming in Nought sir @Qandil Tariq

Comment: edittext.setLongClickable(false);
edittext.setTextIsSelectable(false); 
add these lines also after above code.

Comment: still paste option is coming @Qandil Tariq but only in nought and not in marshmellow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168737/discussion-between-vishnu-and-qandil-tariq).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      FirstName.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```