# Android EditText copy/paste menu issue

Tags: android, menu, android-edittext, copy-paste

I noticed on one of the application screens that when you select the word in EditText there is no context menu for copying/pasting the text. Moreover, a long-click on the empty input field works properly.

This issue is noticeable only in one context in this Activity. My attempts to follow the advice by adding to the element `android:textIsSelectable="true"` led to nothing. Maybe anyone else faced this problem?

Here is my EditText code:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnSend"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnSend"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btnStickers"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnStickers"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background_white_border_corners"
        android:hint="@string/type_message"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: This sounds like that this is the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331404/5499287

Comment: @TobiasLukoschek this link not working for me