# does inheritance violates the basic law of oops..?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

let me first explain what i want to say actually

Suppose a class Sub inheriting the class Super.
now we can excess all no private members of class Super within class Sub. now Suppose the case

```
class Super{
    private int id;
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        System.out.println(sub.getId());
    }
}
```

I know that creating Sub class object will call Super class constructor too.
But the job of constructor is to initialize the fields only -- not to allocate the memory to the object.

Moreover in case of abstract class where the initialization is not allowed we can still use the instance variable of abstract class.

The memory to instance variable will be assigned at time of instance creation only.

Than how can we use the instance fields without even creating the instance.
Doesn't it violets the oops concept..??

Please help over this. And thanks in advance.

Comment: All instances of `Sub` are also instances of `Super.`  When you create an instance of `Sub` that object also has all the fields from `Super.`  That's the definition of `extends`

Comment: "in case of abstract class where the initialization is not allowed" Wrong: fields in an abstract base class can be initialized, by assignment in the declaration or by the constructor.

Comment: i think the private members of Super are not inheritable and cant be an instance field of Sub

Comment: @laune i said that the class cant be instantiated. how can you you intiallize instance field of a class without instantiating it

Comment: @sanidee, no.  The private members are inherited and are still there.  `Sub` just can't access them directly from its own code.

Comment: @lan McLaird  suppose in above case we define a same field id in Sub class
now is it overriding the private field of Super class in Sub class..??

Comment: No.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000137/overriding-private-methods-in-java

Comment: @lan McLaird as you said that the private members are inherited an are still there. Moreover we cant override them. Does it mean the id field declared in class Sub will be a new Field. If yes, then isn't there two fields with the same..??

Comment: "How can you initialize instance field of a class without instantiating it?"  If `AbstractSuper` is an abstract class, and `Sub` is a concrete class that extends it, then when you instantiate a new `Sub`, the new object is also an instance of `AbstractSuper`.  (See Ian's first comment.)  Therefore, it also has the instance fields you defined for `AbstractSuper`.  So, in a way, you _have_ instantiated an `AbstractSuper`, i.e. you've created an object that's an instance of `AbstractSuper`.  You just have to do it via a concrete subclass.

Comment: @sandiee, yes there are now two different fields with the same name, but that's OK, because they're in different namespaces or scopes.  The names don't collide.  `Super` doesn't know about `Sub`s member, and `Sub` can't see `Super`'s, so there's no confusion to the compiler about which is which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confused about what happens when you use the `extends` keyword.  What that keyword means is that a `Sub` is a more-specific *kind of* `Super`.  By the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), all of the properties of `Super` must hold for `Sub` as well.  That means that all of `Super`'s private members (methods and properties) are present in an instance of `Sub`.  It's just that for organizational reasons, the developer of `Super` decided that they didn't want any derived classes messing around with it directly.

Now, how does this relate to memory allocation?  In the case of Java, you are correct that the constructor does not allocate memory.  It just initializes the fields.  The memory allocation is handled by the runtime, and it allocates enough for the whole picture.  Remember, a `Sub` is a `Super` *and then some*.  So it allocates enough memory to hold everything from the entire inheritance chain all the way back up through `java.lang.Object`.

`abstract` classes can, in fact be initialized, or even force their derived classes to initialize their members.  For example:

```
public abstract class Super {
    private int id;
    public Super(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() { return this.id; }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub() {
        super(5); // failure to call this constructor is a compiler error
    }
}
```

Now, because `Sub` can't see `Super`'s private `id` field, it's free to declare a new one of its own.  This *does not* override `Super`'s field.  Any of `Super`'s methods that use that field will still use the one from `Super`.  This could be a little confusing, so the best advice is *don't think of it that way*.  Generally, you'll want to override *methods* not fields.

Comment: @sandiee what Ian says in the code comment is that *not* calling the constructor in the superclass would lead to a compiler error - it demonstrates as he said "`abstract` classes can, in fact be initialized, or even force their derived classes to initialize their members".

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the answer of Ian. Totally. Regarding the title of your question,

> Does inheritance violates the basic law of oops..?

the answer is **it depends**. There is a kind of inheritance that violates *encapsulation* principle: *implementation inheritance*.

You're using implementation inheritance every time you inherit (through `extends` primitive) from a class that is not marked as `abstract`. In that case, to know how to implement your subclass, you need to know the implementation (a.k.a. the code) of methods of the base class. When you override a method, you have to know exactly  which is the behavior of that method in the base class. This kind of code reuse is often referred to as **white-box reuse**.

Quoting the GoF's book, Design Pattern:

> Parent classes often define at least part of their subclasses' physical representation. Because inheritance exposes a subclass to details of its parent's implementation, it's often said that "inheritance breaks encapsulation".

So, to reduce implementation dependencies, you have to follow one of the principles of reusable object-oriented design, which is:

*Program to an interface, not an implementation*

Answer (score 0):

inheritance only concern about what and how is accomplished, not what is promised. If you violate the promises of the base class, what will happen? is there any guarantee that makes you sure it's compatible? -even your compiler will not understand this mistake and you will face a bug in your codes. Such as:

```
class DoubleEndedQueue {

    void insertFront(Node node){
        // ...
        // insert node infornt of queue
    }

    void insertEnd(Node node){
        // ...
        // insert a node at the end of queue
    }

    void deleteFront(Node node){
        // ...
        // delete the node infront of queue
    }

    void deleteEnd(Node node){
         // ...
        // delete the node at the end of queue
    }

}

class Stack extends DoubleEndedQueue {
        // ...
}
```

if the class wants to use inheritance with aim of code reuse, It may inherit a behavior that violates its principal, such as `insertFront`.  Let's also see another code example:

```
public class DataHashSet extends HashSet {
    private int addCount = 0;

    public function DataHashSet(Collection collection) {
            super(collection);
    }

    public function DataHashSet(int initCapacity, float loadFactor) {
            super(initCapacity, loadFactor);
    }

    public boolean function add(Object object) {
            addCount++;
            return super.add(object);
    }

    public boolean function addAll(Collection collection) {
            addCount += collection.size();
            return super.addAll(collection);
    }

    public int function getAddCount(Object object) {
            return addCount;
    }
}
```

I just reimplement `HashSet` with `DataHashSet` class in order to keep track of inserts. In fact, `DataHashSet` inherit and is a subtype of `HashSet`. we can instead of `HashSet` just pass `DataHashSet`(in java is possible). Also, I do override some of the methods of the base class. Is this legitimate from Liskov substitution principle? As I do not make any changes in the behavior of base class just add a track to insert actions, It seems perfectly legitimate. But, I will argue this is obviously a risky inheritance and a buggy code. First, we should see what exactly `add` method do. add one unit to related property and call parent class method. There is a problem with that called `yo-yo`. Look at `addAll` method, first, it adds collection size to related property then call `addAll` in the parent, but what exactly parent `addAll` do? It will call `add` method several times(loop over the collection), which `add` will be called? the `add` in the current class, so, the size of count will be added twice. once when you call addAll and second when parent class will call add method in the child class, that's why we call it yo-yo problem. And another example, imagine:

```
class A {
    void foo(){
        ...
        this.bar();
        ...
    }
    void bar(){
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    //override bar
    void bar(){
        ...
    }
}

class C {
    void bazz(){
        B b = new B();
        // which bar would be called?
        B.foo();
    }
}
```

As you see in `bazz` method which `bar` will be called? the second one the `bar` in class B will be called. but, what is the problem here? the problem is `foo` method in class A will not know anything about the override of `bar` method in class B, Then your invariants may be violated. because foo may expect the only behavior of bar method that is in own class, not something is overridden. This problem is called **fragile base-class problem**.