# Why does a child object call private method of the super class having main method?

Tags: java, inheritance, super, superclass, access-specifier

In the below code, the child class object calls its getBankName() method but instead, the private method getBankName() of parent class is invoked.

```
public class Bank {
    private void getBankName() {
        System.out.println("Bank");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank bank = new MyBank();
        bank.getBankName();
    }
}

class MyBank extends Bank {
    public void getBankName() {
        System.out.println("MyBank");
    }
}
```

Further, if I change the access specifier of parent's method to **public**, then it works fine(child object calls its own method and prints 'MyBank'). Why is the invocation getting affected just because of the access specifier of the parent method??

Comment: As a note, Java convention is that `get` methods _return_ a value; instead of `void`, the type should be `String`, and you should `return "Bank"`.

Comment: Java does not support private method override because of security and encapsulation issues,  check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000137/overriding-private-methods-in-java.

Comment: Very bad design. A super Class should never know a subclass

Comment: Design is not my concern here for this question, just trying to make out why its happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private methods can't be overridden; they're entirely different items, like redeclared (shadowing) fields.

When the visibility of a method is not private, the compiler uses the [`invokevirtual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual) instruction, which is responsible for finding the appropriate override and executing it. However, for a private method, the compiler uses [`invokespecial`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial) (see "Notes"), which explicitly does not allow for overrides.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answered my query. :)