# Members of static nested class in java

Tags: java, nested-class

If I define a member variable inside static nested class in java like this:

```
public class Outer {

    public static class StaticNestedClass {
         private int mMember = 3;
    }

}
```

mMember would be interpreted static because its class is static? 
What about static nested class members in java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `static` on a class doesn't have the same meaning as `static`on a field. The field `mMember` is a private instance field of the nested class `StaticNestedClass`. You can use this nested class as if you were using any other top-level class, as long as you import it or use it with reference to its containing class, ie. Outer.StaticNestedClass. For example,

```
import Outer.StaticNestedClass;

...
StaticNestedClass instance = new StaticNestedClass();
```

or

```
import Outer;

...
Outer.StaticNestedClass instance = new Outer.StaticNestedClass();
```

An inner class cannot declare static members under some rules, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953530/why-does-java-prohibit-static-fields-in-inner-classes).

Answer (score 1):

from the java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> As with class methods and variables, a static nested class is
>   associated with its outer class. And like static class methods, a
>   static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or
>   methods defined in its enclosing class — it can use them only through
>   an object reference.
>
> **Note**: A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its
>   outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class.
>   In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class
>   that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging
>   convenience. Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing
>   class name:
>
> OuterClass.StaticNestedClass For example, to create an object for the
>   static nested class, use this syntax:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
     new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```