# Why we are restricted to declare static member variable in inner Class in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider the below example
 Why we are restricted to declare static member variable in inner Class when **there isn't any restriction on inheriting static variables in Inner classes**?

```
public class Outer {

    public class Inner {

        public static String notAllowed;
        /* Above line give following compilation error 
         The field notAllowed cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression
         */

    }

}
```

But now if my inner class extends other class which contains static variable than this works fine.
Consider below code:

```
public class Outer {

    public class Inner extends InnerBase {
        /* Since it extends InnerBase so we can access Outer.Inner.allowed */ 
        public Inner(){
             Outer.Inner.allowed = null; // Valid statement
        }
    }

}

public class InnerBase {

    public static String allowed;

}
```

So what is the reason for restricting static variable in inner class as **it is achievable through inheritance**?
Am I missing something very basic?

Comment: Because the `Inner` class definition is not static itself?

Comment: poosible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953530/why-does-java-prohibit-static-fields-in-inner-classes

Comment: Note that in your second example, you aren't declaring a `static` field in `Inner`, you are simply assigning it some value.

Comment: There is no inner class definition of a static field here, and no inheritance either. The static variable is visible from the outer scope. The restriction has been lifted in Java 16.

Answer (score 2):

From oracle website:

> 1. As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields.

> 2. Because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.

I understand it this way:

If inner class have their own static field,and static field have to initialize before class instantiate;

But a innner class only exist with an  instance of outterclass ,so it can not initialize its static member before instantiate,then in Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Because in order to access the static field, you will need an instance of the `Outer` class, from which you will have to create an instance of the non-static `Inner` class.

`static` fields are not supposed to be bound to instances and therefore you receive a compilation error.

The [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) specifies:

> Inner classes may not declare static initializers or member
>   interfaces, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant
>   variables, or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible that the purpose of declaring a static variable opposes the purpose of declaring ANY variable in an inner class. Static variables are meant to be used *statically* - in any other static methods and classes, while inner classes imply that those classes serve their outer classes ONLY.

I guess the Java creators just wanted it this way.