# Java 8 error compiling code to add node in linklist but runs correctly in Java 15

Tags: java

Here's the function to add node in singly link list. It is getting executed on Java 15, but for Java 8 it shows the compilation error.

```
public static SinglyLinkedListNode insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode llist, int data, int position) {
// Write your code here
        SinglyLinkedListNode new_node = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
    SinglyLinkedListNode curr_node = llist;
    
    int i=0;
    while(i<position-1)
    {
        curr_node = curr_node.next;
        i++;
    }
    new_node.next = curr_node.next;
    curr_node.next = new_node;
    
    return llist;
}
```

Here's the link for whole problem statement:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list/problem

This is the error:

```
Solution.java:78: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Solution.Result
    public static SinglyLinkedListNode insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode llist, int data, int position) {
                                       ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
Solution.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
        SinglyLinkedListNode llist_head = insertNodeAtPosition(llist.head, data, position);
                                          ^
  symbol:   method insertNodeAtPosition(SinglyLinkedListNode,int,int)
  location: class Solution
2 errors
Exit Status

1
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Needs more code to talk about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifier static is only allowed in constant variable declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440010/modifier-static-is-only-allowed-in-constant-variable-declarations)

Comment: The problem statement doesn't seem to have defined properly for Java 8. SinglyLinkedListNode is not defined in java 8 skeleton code

Comment: @enzo ... no.  It is a different problem.

Comment: @null - this is code that the OP has written himself.  `SinglyLinkedListNode` is presumably >his< class.  (And the compilation error doesn't say that the compiler can't resolve `SinglyLinkedListNode`.)

Comment: Oh... Got it. Thanks @Stephen C for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the first compilation error in Java 8 was that static methods were not allowed in inner classes prior to Java 15.  The restriction was removed as part of the changes to support `record` classes.  (See [Why are static methods allowed inside a non-static inner class in Java 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521280) for some background).

The second error is a consequence of the first one.  The Java 8 compiler has rejected the method declaration ... and then won't resolve it as a symbol.

The simplest solution for Java 8 portability is to remove the `static` modifier from that method.  (Declaring the `Result` class as `static` might be an alternative ...)

Comment: Or make the inner class static

Comment: That is another way, but there might be a reason why the class is not `static`.  (There is no obvious reason for this method to be `static`.)