# inner class and static method java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why cant we have static method in an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975134/why-cant-we-have-static-method-in-an-inner-class)

I don't know why an inner class cannot have a static method. Why is it wrong?

```
class A1
{
    class B1
    {
         static void fun()
        {
            System.out.println("HIII");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A1 a = new A1();
        A1.B1 b = new a.B1();
        b.fun();
    }
}
```

If an outer class object can access a static method and a variable `y` not a inner class get the access? What are the problems.

Comment: dupplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975134/why-cant-we-have-static-method-in-an-inner-class

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/975134/645270)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your non-static inner class has a static method and you are trying to call it from static method of outer class.

Non-static inner class is "relevant" only in context of instance of outer class because it can access outer class' nont-static methods and to `this` of outer class (using `A1.this`).

Bottom line: if you want to do this mark inner class as static too:

```
static class B1
{
     static void fun()
    {
        System.out.println("HIII");
    }
}
```

Now you can call its static methods from outer class's static method.