# Hackerrank : Illegal static declaration in inner class Solution.Result

Tags: java

Most of the time when I  solve a problem in hackerrank the compiler gives me this  error:olution.java:81: error: *Illegal static declaration in inner class Solution.Result
public static DoublyLinkedListNode sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode llist, int data) {*
it happens even if  I do not write any single line of code. I try to remove the static keyword  but then it does not find the method.

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.math.*;
  import java.security.*;
  import java.text.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.util.concurrent.*;
  import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static class DoublyLinkedListNode {
    public int data;
    public DoublyLinkedListNode next;
    public DoublyLinkedListNode prev;

    public DoublyLinkedListNode(int nodeData) {
        this.data = nodeData;
        this.next = null;
        this.prev = null;
    }
}

static class DoublyLinkedList {
    public DoublyLinkedListNode head;
    public DoublyLinkedListNode tail;

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    public void insertNode(int nodeData) {
        DoublyLinkedListNode node = new DoublyLinkedListNode(nodeData);

        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = node;
            node.prev = this.tail;
        }

        this.tail = node;
    }
}

public static void printDoublyLinkedList(DoublyLinkedListNode node, String sep, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter) throws IOException {
    while (node != null) {
        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(node.data));

        node = node.next;

        if (node != null) {
            bufferedWriter.write(sep);
        }
    }
 }

 class Result {

/*
 * Complete the 'sortedInsert' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER_DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER_DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST llist
 *  2. INTEGER data
 */

/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * DoublyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     DoublyLinkedListNode next;
 *     DoublyLinkedListNode prev;
 * }
 *
 */

  public static DoublyLinkedListNode sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode llist, intdata) {
// Write your code here

 }

}

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

    int t = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    for (int tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
        DoublyLinkedList llist = new DoublyLinkedList();

        int llistCount = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int i = 0; i < llistCount; i++) {
            int llistItem = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

            llist.insertNode(llistItem);
        }

        int data = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        DoublyLinkedListNode llist1 = sortedInsert(llist.head, data);

        printDoublyLinkedList(llist1, " ", bufferedWriter);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
    }

    bufferedWriter.close();

    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is ypu have an non static inner class with an static methode 
Take a look at this: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672563/inner-class-and-static-method-java)

Comment: As Rupesh D.C mentioned in his answer, move the sortedInsert method to the Solution class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 public static DoublyLinkedListNode sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode llist, intdata) {

      // Write your code here

 }.
```

Place this method *outside* **Result** `class` and *inside* **Solution** `class`.

Comment: Please format your code this is hard to read.

Comment: It is not my code, and it is alreayd formatted.