# Illegical static declaration in inner class

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.lang.*;

class mythread implements Runnable {

    Thread t1;
    String name = "";

    mythread(String thname){

        name = thname;
        t1 = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("Child thread starting" + t1 );
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        for(int i = 5 ; i > 0 ;i--){
            System.out.println("Name Of Thread" + t1 + i);
        }   
    }


    class t {

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            mythread m1 = new mythread("Child Thread 1");
            mythread m2 = new mythread("Child Thread 2");

            try {

            for(int i = 5 ; i > 0 ;i--) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread" + i);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

            System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted");
        }


     }
}
```

THE ERROR IS GIVEN IN `public static line`:

```
Illegical static declaration in inner class `mythread.t` modifier static is allowed in constant variable declaration
```

Comment: Just a side node: the Java convention for class names is camel case, i.e. `MyThread`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You can't have static method in inner class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975134/why-cant-we-have-static-method-in-an-inner-class

Comment: you wrote 2 classes in one file

Comment: You declare two public classes in one file, the inner one should be private. Also as @Thomas said, usingthe CamelCase convention is a must. Split the class should solve your problem.

Comment: @PhilippSander unless both classes are public, that's allowed. And since there's no `public class`, both have default scope.

Comment: yes! i meant something else :)  if you look at the brackets, class t is a field the class my thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the error message, inner class cannot access the static variables;

either remove the class t or declare it static; it works:

```
// class t {   // Remove it

        public static void main(String args[]) {

            mythread m1 = new mythread("Child Thread 1");
            mythread m2 = new mythread("Child Thread 2");

            try {

            for(int i = 5 ; i > 0 ;i--) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread" + i);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

            System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted");
        }


    // }
```

Answer (score 1):

there are some missing brackets

```
import java.lang.*;

class mythread implements Runnable {

    Thread t1;
    String name = "";

    mythread(String thname){

        name = thname;
        t1 = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("Child thread starting" + t1 );
    }

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        for(int i = 5 ; i > 0 ;i--){
            System.out.println("Name Of Thread" + t1 + i);
        }   
    }
} // was missing (for closing class mythread)


class t {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        mythread m1 = new mythread("Child Thread 1");
        mythread m2 = new mythread("Child Thread 2");

        try {

            for(int i = 5 ; i > 0 ;i--) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread" + i);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){

            System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted");
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can’t have static method in a nested inner class because an inner class is implicitly associated with an object of its outer class so it cannot define any static method for itself.
So ,here you have too remove class t
//class t {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    mythread m1 = new mythread("Child Thread 1");
    mythread m2 = new mythread("Child Thread 2");

    try {

        for(int i = 5 ; i > 0 ;i--) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread" + i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){

        System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted");
    }

 }
```