# Static methods for operations on inner class

Tags: java, static, linked-list, static-methods, inner-classes

I'm working through *Algorithms Fourth Edition* (Sedgewick) and am confused by some of the linked-list exercises which seem to be asking to implement static methods for the non-static nodes. For example,

> **1.3.27** Write a method `max()` that takes a reference to the first node in a
>   linked list as argument and returns the value of the maximum key in
>   the list. Assume that all keys are positive integers, and return `0` if
>   the list is empty.

or

> **1.3.31** Implement a nested class DoubleNode for building doubly-linked lists,
>   where each node contains a reference to the item preceding it and the
>   item following it in the list (`null` if there is no such item). Then
>   implement static methods for the following tasks: insert at the
>   beginning, insert at the end, remove from the beginning, remove from
>   the end, insert before a given node, insert after a given node, and
>   remove a given node.

As I understand (and confirmed by SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975134/why-cant-we-have-static-method-in-a-non-static-inner-class)) this isn't possible. As expected, Eclipse gives errors if I try to write a static method in the superclass:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<Item> {

    public static void insertStart(DoubleNode first) {
        // implementation
    }

    private class DoubleNode {
        Item item;
        DoubleNode next;
        DoubleNode previous;

    }
}
```

(gives the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type DoubleNode`); or in the inner class:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<Item> {

    private class DoubleNode {
        Item item;
        DoubleNode next;
        DoubleNode previous;

        public static void insertStart(DoubleNode first) {
            // implementation
        }
    }
}
```

(gives the error `The method insertStart cannot be declared static; static methods can only be declared in a static or top level type`).

I could write the required methods as *instance methods* for the `DoublyLinkedList` class, and this would seem most natural to me.

However, I feel that I might be missing out on something important here. The author explicitly states that the methods should be static, and also suggests taking a reference to the first node as an argument (which would be unnecessary for an instance method as the class will have an instance variable for the first node). What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make nested classes as `static`. You will lose the constraint of having an enclosing parent class instance, but it will allow you to operate on `DoubleNode`s from a static method :

```
// This will compile
public class DoublyLinkedList<Item> {

    public static <T> void insertStart(DoublyLinkedList<T> list, DoubleNode<T> first) {
        // implementation
    }

    private static class DoubleNode<E> {
        E item;
        DoubleNode<E> next;
        DoubleNode<E> previous;

    }
}
```

Two things to notice here : As you can see, when making the inner class static, you need to provide it its own type parameter (in this case, `E`). In your code you didn't need to do that, because any `DoubleNode` instance was guaranteed to have a containing `DoublyLinkedList` instance, which already determines what `Item` will be.

Secondly, you need to introduce a type parameter for your static method ("`<T>`"), so you can enforce the same generic type for both arguments. You could also have done this and get away with it :

```
public static void insertStart(DoublyLinkedList<?> list, DoubleNode<?> first) {
    ...
}
```

In case you're wondering, this is also how it is done in the JDK's `LinkedList` implementation :

```
// Source : Oracle JDK 1.7.0_67 lib - inside LinkedList class
private static class Node<E> {
     E item;
     Node<E> next;
     Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
       this.item = element;
       this.next = next;
       this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, I do agree that it is more natural to write those methods as instance members ; that's how it's generally done in OOP libraries. I don't have a copy of Sedgewick's book but it looks like he's trying to teach you both nested class manipulation and list implementations at the same time ;)

Comment: Thank you. It's interesting to see the JDK implementation. What's the importance of that constraint in this context?

Comment: The constraint is what's preventing your code from successfully compiling. It is there to make sure you can't use a variable to hold an "independent" `DoubleNode` object, or define a static or external method that returns a value of type `DoubleNode`.  The point is to encourage encapsulation ("keep all `DoubleNode` stuff inside `DoublyLinkedList` instance methods"), but in this case it goes against the "make a static method" statement.

Comment: You may read a basic introduction on the various nested class types here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Okay. The code in your original answer doesn't compile - it seems to be an issue with the `Item` parametrisation. 

I get the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type Item` on lines 4 and 9.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just realized there is an `Item` type parameter to your whole list class. I'm gonna correct this in a minute.