# Declare static variables in inner non-static class

Tags: java, inner-classes

Why does this line:

```
static final Integer intValue = 1;
```

give a compiler error, while this line declared in the same way:

```
static final String strValue = "aaa";
```

does not.

The full code:

```
public class InnerClass {
    class NestedClass {
        static final String strValue = "aaa";
        static final Integer intValue = 1;
    }
}
```

Compile time error:

> The field intValue cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the compiler error.

Comment: Done, added error @Turing85

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't give an error when it is a primitive `int`

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that `Integer` is a class and although you can assign the int literal `1` to an instance of an `Integer` at runtime, it would still result in a wrapper object allocated on the heap, so it's not a constant expression. Changing to `int` should make it work. String literals are interned and they get a constant chunk of memory so those _are_ constant expressions.

Comment: Note that I initially closed the question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509919/field-cannot-be-declared-static-in-a-non-static-inner-type-unless-initialized-wi), but on deeper reading saw that it really isn't a dupe and actually (to me) is an interesting question.

Comment: Please, mention the JDK version where you see a compilation error. The same code fails using JDK 11 but successfully compiles when JDK 17 is used.

Answer (score 3):

It is implied that you're using an older version of Java (such as 11), as this is not reproducible with either 17 (openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18) or 18 (openjdk version "18" 2022-03-22). For this answer, I'm using Java 11 ("11.0.14" 2022-01-18 LTS) as the error you describe is reproducible using that version.

Here's a compilation attempt using Java 11:

```
% cat Test.java 
public class Test {
    class NestedClass {
        static final Integer intValue = 1;
    }
}

% javac -version
javac 11.0.14

% javac Test.java
Test.java:3: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class Test.NestedClass
        static final Integer intValue = 1;
                             ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
1 error
```

Why did that fail? The [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) (again, for Java 11) states that you cannot define an inner class with a static member, *unless* that member is a constant:

> *"It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable"*

Why did it work with a String - `static final String strValue = "aaa"`? Because [a String is a constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3):

> *"A String object has a constant (unchanging) value"*

What else besides String is a constant? A [final primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> *"A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression"*

So what happens if you change the type from `Integer` to `int` - does that work? Yes, it works fine:

```
class InnerClass {
    class NestedClass {
        static final int intValue = 1; // no problems in Java 11 using primitive
    }
}
```

Or you could try a later Java version, such as 17:

```
% javac -version
javac 17.0.2
% javac Test.java
%
```

I did not look further into why later versions allow `static final Integer`, even though later versions of JLS (such as version 18) still contain [the same wording](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) which suggests `Integer` should not work (even though it clearly does).

> *"A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression"*