# Not able to identify what type of nested class by static method call in java

Tags: java, inner-classes

Usually, we can identify all the classes, methods & data members by seeing their signatures.

Ex: Math.sqrt(), System.out.println

Math - class

sqrt - static method

print/println - instance method

But Not able to identify static methods of nested classes.

package so;

```
class Outer {
    static String outerVar = "ABC"; 
    class InsInner {
        static void show() {
            System.out.println("Instance inner "+outerVar);
        }
    }
    static class StaticInner {
        static void show() {
            System.out.println("Static inner class static method "+outerVar);
        }
    }
}
public class NestedClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer.InsInner.show();
        Outer.StaticInner.show();
    }
}
```

Why both static and non static classes have same convention?

```
Outer.InsInner.show();
Outer.StaticInner.show();
```

Comment: Why would they use different conventions?  The static attribute of a class is irrelevant in the context of calling a static method.

Comment: I hops this link helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class?rq=2

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms, and therefore so is `StaticInner `. It is a static, nested class. Your question is somewhat confused.

Comment: The _inner class_ is _InsInner_, and the _nested class_ is _StaticInner_.  The class you have named _NestedInner_ is just another class, it's not nested.

Comment: A similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/975173/17758716.

Answer (score 1):

Because `show()` is `static` in both places. When a method is `static` it does not require an instance to operate, so you don't need an `InsInner` or `StaticInner` to call either `show()` and the calls look the same. If you make `show()` an instance method, then it would have to differ. Like,

```
class Outer {
    static String outerVar = "ABC";

    class InsInner {
        void show() {
            System.out.println("Instance inner " + outerVar);
        }
    }

    static class StaticInner {
        void show() {
            System.out.println("Static inner class static method " + outerVar);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Outer().new InsInner().show();
        new Outer.StaticInner().show();
    }
}
```